# datacolumn select by custom object

Tags: vb.net, select, datacolumn, custom-type

How can I select from Datatable in VB.net all rows which contains my custom object? - actually its type is `INotifyPropertyChanged`.
I consider using `datatable.select` method with filter expression, however no idea how comparision works with select.

Answer (score 0):

Try using LINQ's `Where` method, something like,

```
' this will return a list of DataRow object
Dim rows = datatable.AsEnumerable().Where(Function(x) TypeOf x("mycolumn") Is INotifyPropertyChanged).ToList()
```

OR

```
' this will return a new DataTable with your selected rows
Dim dt2 = datatable.AsEnumerable().Where(Function(x) TypeOf x("mycolumn") Is INotifyPropertyChanged).CopyToDataTable()
```